# Is it possible to put a bootstrap glyphicon inside of a {{ Form::submit(' ')}} - Laravel

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to change this:

```
{{ Form::submit('Delete this User', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) }}
```

to something like this:

```
{{ Form::submit('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-delete"></i>', array('class' => '')) }}
```

I know that the second option isn't correct, anyone knows how to write it in a correct way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use a `<button>` of type submit, which adds more flexibility then a submit input:

```
{{Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-delete"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => ''))}}
```

To make it clear, this is the class method:

```
public function button($value = null, $options = array())
{
   if ( ! array_key_exists('type', $options) )
   {
       $options['type'] = 'button';
   }

    return '<button'.$this->html->attributes($options).'>'.$value.'</button>';
}
```

As you can see, `$value` holds anything you put inside the `<button>` tag, so placing the icon there should work - I use this with Fontawesome icons and it works fine, I personally tend to use those instead of Glyphicon but the principle remains the same.

By using `Form::submit()`, instead, you create an `<input type="submit"` which cannot accept html as content of the `value` attribute, that's why your solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks Damien! This also works: {{Form::button('<i></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'))}}

Comment: Yeah, but the class should be assigned to the `<i></i>` tags, not to the form tag, althoug eventually it works anyway that's not idealy correct

Comment: Okay I put it back like you said :)

Comment: @Anyone how do you create a FORM HELPER CLASS without generating FORM html? Seriously, this is not the place for random bashing, go write a blog post about it

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
{{ Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', array('class'=>'btn btn-default', 'type'=>'submit')) }}
```

Comment: hey, @Damiey  or anyone else, can you please help me what if i want to implement the same for 
`{!! Form:text() !!}`
How we can implement this ? any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to implement a glyphicon in a text input?? @Tarunn

Comment: Maybe he wants to put a button inside an entry like those used to display the calendar in a text field. That can be done with bootstrap so : <div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    {{ Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>') }} -->more buttons...
  </div>
  {!! Form:text() !!}
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I used `Html::linkRoutes` to create a button and cannot implement the methods you guys mentioned before...  Any one have any guesses? Heres my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          {{ Html::linkRoute('posts.index', '<< Back to blog', [], ['class' => 'btn2 btn2-default']) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your icon class to your class array like:

```
array('class' => 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
```