# How to add Glyphicon to {{!! Form::Button !!}}

Tags: html, laravel, glyphicons

I'm using Laravel 5.0 and have the following problem.

This is my button:

```
{!! Form::button('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#'.$category->id)) !!}
```

How can I add something like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
```

I'm came across to this -> [Is it possible to put a bootstrap glyphicon inside of a {{ Form::submit(' ')}} - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746049/is-it-possible-to-put-a-bootstrap-glyphicon-inside-of-a-formsubmit%5D) but it is for the notation wihtout exclamation marks (It does not work for me).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Laravel, so I don't know how it taps into CSS. If I were to do it in an HTML/CSS environment, I would do the example below using Pesudo Classes.

```
.btn-danger:before {font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';content:"\e020"} 
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> Blah</button>
```

You don't have to use .btn-danger, instead use the class/Id that you are attaching to the button.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8cegbmm/)

Comment: Thank you very much it works like a charm. (If anyone knows how to do this in the Laravel way I would appreciate a response.)

The thing is, it does not work for {!! Form::submit !!}} Do you also know a workaround for that? (-:

Comment: {{ Form::submit(array('class' => 'CSS CLASS HERE')) }} - If you attach a css class to the submit button, you can apply the font-family style to it.

Comment: Okay thanks I know that it should works the same way but not in my case unfortunately. I guess we need an expert in Laravel to help us out. Thanks anyway. Shall I mark you answer as right an open another topic so that you could earn the points? No problem, I can do this!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
{{ Form::button('', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove']) }}
```